# Can't access the Android Device from Remote machine within same lan

Tags: android, windows, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver , android server for mobile browser automation.

Android device(where the android server is running ) is connected to the  remote machine  10.0.0.158  and i want to access this machine from development machine 10.0.0.138 [ where i will run the webdriver code for device automation using eclipse),i want to mention one thing that in both of these machine android sdk is present.

In the Android driver reference site[ https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver ] they  mention about the remote connection procedure by using  socat but  those commands are for linux os  which is not working in windows , commands are given below

```
# Instal socat, one time setup
$sudo apt-get install socat

$socat TCP-LISTEN:8081,fork TCP:localhost:8080
```

Can any one tell me for windows what commands will be used  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last i have solved this problem.

I am sharing the procedure  hopefully it will helpfull for all

To access android device remotely in windows environment we need to do the following steps

**1  In the remote machine (i.e the machine which is connected with the android device) first download socat-x.x.x.x.zip from  http://blog.gentilkiwi.com/programmes/socat#englishversion**

2 **Now through command  prompt go to that folder where you have downloaded the socat zip [ for me i have download it in E: drive  socat folder ]**

3 **Now in the same command prompt  give the command adb.devices [ i am assuming that platform-tools folder path is already set in the environment variable ]
to check weather Remote machine is detecting your desired device or not, if the machine detect the device correctly  then it will show device id  then  the text device  otherwise it will show  device id  then the text offline**

4 If the device is detected properly in the remote machine then either star the android server in  the device manually or  give the command

```
adb -shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.openqa.selenium.android.app/.MainActivity
```

if more than one device is there the give the serial id of your device

```
adb -s <serialId> shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.openqa.selenium.android.app/.MainActivity
```

5 Once Android driver started in the device  then  give the command

```
adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

6 then give  the command

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8081,fork TCP:localhost:8080
```

[ i have given 8081 but we can give 8082 or 8083 or any port which is not in use ]

so now everything is ready in the remote machine

to verify  weather Android WebDriver server can be accessed from  from any machine or network interface open the url  `http://remote machine ip:8081/wd/hub` 
in the firefox browser in any machine

if every thing is fine then then it will show a blank page in firefox browser

7 Now at the development machine [ i.e where code will be execute through eclipse ] just modify the below code

```
WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(); 

 and change it to  

WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver("http://remote machine ip:8081/wd/hub/");
```

8 Now click on the run button in the eclipse , you will see the output in the android device which is connected in the remote machine.